# Key found in dictionary that shouldn't exist

Tags: python

Hey having some issues here. I am reading a file with keys and translations, a typical line in the file is like so:

```
"welcome-screen" = "Welcome to the app!"
```

The file also has a language prefix stored in `lang_key`, e.g. `lang_key = eng`.

Currently I am trying to build a dict:

```
strings_dict = {}

f = open(os.path.join(root, file), 'r')
for line in f:
    strings = line.split('"')[1::2]
    if len(strings) == 2:
        if strings[0] in strings_dict:
            entry = strings_dict[strings[0]]
            entry[lang_key] = strings[1]
            strings_dict[strings[0]] = entry
            print("modified entry")
        else:
            entry = {lang_key: strings[1]}
            strings_dict[strings[0]] = entry
            print("made entry")
```

The `line.split` pulls the words out of the quotation marks. e.g the line above becomes `[welcome-screen, Welcome to the app!]`. The key is the first word `welcome-screen` if it's already in the dictionary I want to pull its value out of the dictionary (the value is also a dictionary) and add an item for the key `lang_key`. If the key is not already in the dictionary I want to create a new entry. However when debugging it seems to print `modified entry" every single time. Not once does it create a new entry. Why is this happening?

Comment: I just tested this and the only issue I found was that lang_key should be in quotes when you add it to the dictionary. After fixing that, I see the output: "made entry".

Comment: @jeremynealbrown lang_key is actually a var. I don't think I made it clear in my question. Edited now. Shouldn't need quotes if it's a var with a string inside right?

Comment: I can't reproduce either. Are you sure you are not leaving out something essential regarding `strings_dict`?

Comment: Are you sure your indentation doesn’t contain anything unexpected? If you’re on Python 2, run your script with `python2 -tt`. If you’re on Python 3, disregard this comment =)

Comment: Also, what’s the output of `print(strings_dict)` after the loop?